# Java : Create 1 method to enter 5 numbers into a static array

Tags: java

I am stuck about an exercise. I have to create 2 methods.

For the first method, I would like to enter 5 numbers (via an input)

```
public static void enterNumber(int[] tab, int numeral){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int number = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<tab.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Entrer number " + (i+1) + " : ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            tab[y++] = tab[i];
        }   

    }
```

Then, I create `display` method to display the numbers.

```
public static void display(int[] tab, int numeral){
        for(int x = 0; x<tab.length; x++){
            System.out.println(tab[x]);
        }
    }
```

I called my methods:

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
int number = 0;

enterNumber(tab, number);
display(tab, number);
```

In my input I have this:

```
Entrer number 1 : 2
Entrer number 2 : 4
Entrer number 3 : 3
Entrer number 4 : 9
Entrer number 5 : 1
```

However, in my display, I only get the value `0` why ? I have to retrieve the values `2,4,3,9,1`.
I don't understand.

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You never put the number you enter into `tab`, so it's not there when you display `tab`.

Comment: @azurefrog: my problem is here ? `tab[y++] = tab[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually assigning the input value into your array.

```
tab[y++] = tab[i];
```

should be

```
tab[i] = input.nextInt();
```

You can get rid of the numeral parameter and the y and numebr variables, you're not using them.  You should also close the scanner.